# Replace last / in notepad ++ with some other

Tags: notepad++

I have list of URLs like

http://example.com/data/fgh/xyz

I want to replace last / with ?id=

http://example.com/data/fgh?id=xyz

Thanx in adavance.

Comment: would be easy with a tool such as ``sed`` or ``perl``. Do you really want to do it with ``notepad++`` ?

Comment: can you tell me how to do with sed or perl, i have not used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work.

Replace

Find what: `\/(^[\/]*)$`

Replace with: `?=$1` (or possibly with `?=\1` although for some reason mine only worked with $1...)

Make sure to check "Regular expression" at the bottom:

[image]

Comment: thanx for reply.